# php , mysql insertion with $ sign not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php code which will insert a value into a database table. I am using MySql. Here I have to store a string which contain '$' sign in it (eg.$V#CDFBvQi). But when I store this value, before storing I want to replace the substring '$' with '\$', so that the word will be like this \$V#CDFBvQi before storing. I used the below PHP code for replacing the substring.

```
$dbp = $_POST['varname']; // here $dbp value is $V#CDFBvQi.
if (strpos($dbp, '$') !== false) {
    $dbp = str_replace("$", "\\$", $dbp);
}
echo $dbp; //here $dbp value is \$V#CDFBvQi.
```

And this code works fine.
But When I insert the value $dbp (which is now \$V#CDFBvQi), my database table only contain $V#CDFBvQi. Here is my MySql insertion code.

```
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root");
mysql_select_db("dbsamplename", $link);
mysql_query("insert into sampletable values('".$dbp."')");
```

How can I do it ? Please advise as I am very beginner to PHP.

Comment: Use "mysql_real_escape_string" or change to a non deprecated MySQL API (mysqli or PDO being the usual) that has parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql extention is deprecated and should not be used. Use mysqli with prepared statements and you don't need to worry about escaping the string. I believe following code will solve your problem.

Example:

```
$stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("insert into sampletable values(?)");
/* Bind parameters */
$stmt -> bind_param("s", $dbp);
/* Execute it */
$stmt -> execute();
```

for full examples see: http://mattbango.com/notebook/code/prepared-statements-in-php-and-mysqli/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for giving solutions, but this solved my issue.

```
$dbp = str_replace("$", "\\\\$", $dbp);
```

Thanks.